# shared memory organize threads and blocks

Tags: cuda

I am using shared memory in my program and the problem is that when I change the number of threads and blocks ,the results are changing also.I may take the right results for some configuration but wrong for another.

I am trying to process an 80x64 = 5120 image.That's why I am creating :

```
const int NUM_THREADS = 16;
dim3 dimGrid(  ColsNum / NUM_THREADS  , RowsNum / NUM_THREADS );
dim3 dimBlock( NUM_THREADS ,NUM_THREADS );
```

So , taking 4x5  = 20 blocks each with 16x16 = 256 threads  = 5120 elements.

Now , the problem arises with the use of TILE width .I am not sure how to choose this width.What should I have in mind?

The above configuration (without using shared memory) works fine.

But when using shared memory and altering the size of TILE width and size of threads I am getting these various results.One of them is  also an error "unspecified launch failure " , so it is a memory issue?

If I run ptxas (all the kernels I have):

```
78027 bytes gmem, 72 bytes cmem[3]
Used 8 registers, 368 bytes cmem[0]
Used 32 registers, 5408 bytes smem, 376 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[2]
Used 30 registers, 3328 bytes smem, 416 bytes cmem[0], 32 bytes cmem[2]
Used 13 registers, 368 bytes cmem[0]
Used 16 registers, 416 bytes cmem[0]
Used 32 registers, 5408 bytes smem, 376 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[2]
Used 26 registers, 392 bytes cmem[0], 32 bytes cmem[2]
Used 24 registers, 5408 bytes smem, 368 bytes cmem[0], 24 bytes cmem[2]
0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
```

So , the shared and constant memory sizes are ok.

```
__shared__ float sharedMa[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];

int bx = blockIdx.x , by = blockIdx.y;
int tx = threadIdx.x , ty = threadIdx.y;
int RowIdx = ty + by * TILE_WIDTH;
int ColIdx = tx + bx * TILE_WIDTH;


if ( RowIdx >= RowsNum || ColIdx >= ColsNum) return;

int J = RowIdx * ColsNum + ColIdx;


sharedMa[ty][tx] = *( devMa + J );//devMa is a float * argument

__syncthreads();

.../calculations

__syncthreads();

*( devMa + J ) = sharedMa[ty][tx];
```

Comment: Unspecified launch failure is often related to memory boundary violations. Use cuda memcheck to check the memory accesses. You are not providing a fully compilable and executable code. Revise the relation between J, the tile size and the thread grid size.

Comment: @JackOLantern:I noticed that when I give the same dimensions of block and tile  width ,it gives the correct results.Else,it gives "Invalid __shared__ write of size" "Address is out of bounds" but I can't figure...

Comment: @JackOLantern:Hmm, first of all can you tell me please , the tile width should be always the same as the block size?Because then ,why are we calling it tile width and not leaving it as block size.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will surely get that "Invalid shared write of size" error if the block size exceed the TILE_WIDTH, otherwise there should be no error.